# How to check [] when server response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dio

How to check `[]` when server response in `Flutter`?

```
{
   "Status": true,
   "Data": []
}
```

If "Data" has value, It will return the following

```
{
   "Status": true,
   "Data": {
      "id": "123",
      "pass": "456"
    }
}
```

I'm using `dio` for requesting API.

Comment: Your "Data" property can contain JSON object or JSON array?

Comment: @Aleksandar yes

Comment: like its just an idea that is when you are fetching the response you can have response["data"].length if it returns an exception it is JSON object or it will be a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat value of your Data property as `dynamic` and decide based on data type how to approach parsing. So let's say you have a model class A, with properties:

```
class Order {
  final String status;
  final dynamic data;

  Order({this.status, this.data});

  factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Brand(
        status: json['Status'],
        data: json['Data'],
      );
}
```

Once you parse your response successfully, you can either expand on that model class tu parse different properties (additional ones) to contain list or objects or an object. In case you need to check against object type, you can do this:

```
if (order.data is List) {
  // Code that handles JSON list response
} else if (order.data is Map<String, dynamic>) {
  // Code that handles JSON object response
}
```